# Keeping one fragment with multiple views using ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a few questions on what I want to achieve and how much more do I need to go or if I need to go toward a different direction.

Here's a mockup on what I want to do:

[image]

The user should be able to :

-swipe left or right

-click on the arrows on the top to go left or right

The collection of views is not fixed (It's dynamic and it's a number pulled from the db)

Right now, I have read up on ViewPager and I think it's the closest thing I can use to achieve what I want to do.

Here's my code:

```
//ScorePager.java

public class ScorePager extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    ActionBar actionbar;
    ViewPager viewPager = null;

    public static final String TAG ="ScorePager";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_view);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new myAdapter(fragmentManager));

    }

    private class myAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public myAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {

            super(fragmentManager);
        }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i){
                Fragment fragment = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "get Item is called " + i);
                if (i == 0) {
                    fragment = new ScoreFragment();
                }
               if (i == 1) {
                    fragment = new ScoreFragmentB();
                }

                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount () {
            Log.d(TAG, "get Count is called");
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, I will at some point have too many fragments to store. E.g. if I have 20 new views I need to show, I will have to have 20 fragments in the way I am coding above.

Right now, I have two Fragments and two views shown hardcoded. Is there a way to make a dynamic fragment layout? I've never worked with dynamics views, so I was wondering to make this process cleaner and with less code.

Is it possible for me to have one fragment and one layout view. If so, how do I change the view state with just one fragment and one view?

Also, it seems like a tabbed title bar is the only option with ViewPager, if I want to use arrows like such in the image, is there a way to insert those without having multiple tabs to scroll across.

Where can I go from here?

Comment: Is number of fragments constant or it is changing when your app is running.

Comment: number of fragments will change. The number of fragments will depend on a number stored in db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Is there a way to make a dynamic fragment layout?
```

I don't understand why you need a dynamic fragment layout, as according to your little diagram above, all the views look almost similar, except for the arrows (whose visibility you can always change based upon the position).

```
Is it possible for me to have one fragment and one layout view.
```

Since your layout of all the fragments is similar, you should try using [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) instead of a [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html). FragmentPagerAdapter is the subclass of PagerAdapter. A very simple example is given [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html).

```
If so, how do I change the view state with just one fragment and one view?
```

You can change the view state based upon the position in the `instantiateItem()`.

```
Also, it seems like a tabbed title bar is the only option with ViewPager, if I want to use arrows like such in the image, is there a way to insert those without having multiple tabs to scroll across.
```

You are mistaken. As shown in the tutorial [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html), they are not using tabbed title bar. For your case, I'd suggest have the 2 arrows you are going to use for navigation in the activity, and change their visibility on/off based upon the position you get `onPageSelected()` by setting a [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) on the viewpager. On click of the arrows, simply update the position of the viewpager by using the following code

```
public void moveToNextPage(View view) {
    //it doesn't matter if you're already in the last item
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
}

public void moveToPreviousPage(View view) {
    //it doesn't matter if you're already in the first item
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Yeah they the views are very similar. The only differences would be dynamic text changes per view and I plan on having a different image in the center per view. Also, in the case of the arrows, I can hide the title bar but I am wondering if there are built in arrows (I don't see any), so I would just have to put arrow images and link them to fragment instances?

Comment: Yes, there are no built in arrows that you will find. Put arrow images and `onClick` of them move to next and previous page. Also, since you have a similar design, no need to use different fragments. You can use one layout, and manipulate its content based upon the position in the adapter.

Comment: so I get the position and then change the visibility or add a switch or if-else statement based on what to display.

Comment: @Antrrormet, how do I change the visibility of the arrows depending on the position? How do I know it's on first position and last position?

Comment: Implement viewpager [onPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use fragments in the ViewPager, you can use regular views.

Instead of overriding `getItem`, use these methods :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(...);
    ...
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v,0);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((TextView) view);
}
```

Comment: how do I delete a view from my viewpager if an arraylist of items?

Comment: If what ? If you change the items you need to update the adapter with notifyDatasetChanged method.